# How to test value of struct field that has dynamic type

Tags: rust, dynamic

I'm trying to write test for my simple log structure, which is supposed to hold many types such as console, buffer, files etc.

```
pub struct Logger
{
    pub files: Vec<Box<dyn std::io::Write>>
}
```

I want to test it similar as it is in [chapter](https://rust-cli.github.io/book/tutorial/testing.html) of rust doc.

```
 let writer = Box::new(Vec::new());
 let mut log: log::Logger = log::Logger
 {
     files: vec![Box::new(writer)],
 };
 log.info("Info message");
 // Check if buffer value is correct.
 assert_eq!(log.files[0], b"[Info]: Info message"); // wrong types
```

I tried by getting back object using things like as_mut(), clone(), but I don't know how to cast it to Vec. Also at this point it is not possibly to use writer object due to move.

Can i somehow compare those 2 values for this test or field should be write differently( if yes, how?)

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to give more details than "[it does not work](https://coderanch.com/wiki/660111/Doesnt-Work-Useless)". At the very least please provide a short self-contained example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe just do a simple downcast in unit test if you don't want to add any extra code.

```rs
use std::any::Any;

pub struct Logger {
    pub files: Vec<Box<dyn std::io::Write>>,
}

fn main() {
    let buffer = Box::new(Vec::new());
    let mut log: Logger = Logger {
        files: vec![buffer],
    };
    let writer = log.files[0].as_mut();
    writer.write(b"[Info]: Info message").unwrap();
    let buffer = unsafe { &*(&log.files[0] as *const dyn Any as *const Box<Vec<u8>>) };
    assert_eq!(buffer.as_slice(), b"[Info]: Info message");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is best suited for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`std::any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/)

```rust
use std::any::Any;

trait MyTrait: std::io::Write {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

impl<T> MyTrait for T
where
    T: std::io::Write + Any,
{
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

pub struct Logger {
    pub files: Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait>>,
}

fn main() {
    let writer = Box::new(Vec::new());
    let mut log: Logger = Logger {
        files: vec![Box::new(writer)],
    };
    // Check if buffer value is correct.
    assert_eq!(
        log.files[0].as_any().downcast_ref::<Vec<u8>>().unwrap(),
        b"[Info]: Info message"
    ); // wrong types
}
```

[Run on Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=use%20std%3A%3Aany%3A%3AAny%3B%0A%0Atrait%20MyTrait%3A%20std%3A%3Aio%3A%3AWrite%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20as_any(%26self)%20-%3E%20%26dyn%20Any%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CT%3E%20MyTrait%20for%20T%0Awhere%0A%20%20%20%20T%3A%20std%3A%3Aio%3A%3AWrite%20%2B%20Any%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20as_any(%26self)%20-%3E%20%26dyn%20Any%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20struct%20Logger%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20files%3A%20Vec%3CBox%3Cdyn%20MyTrait%3E%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20writer%20%3D%20Box%3A%3Anew(Vec%3A%3Anew())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20log%3A%20Logger%20%3D%20Logger%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20files%3A%20vec!%5BBox%3A%3Anew(writer)%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Check%20if%20buffer%20value%20is%20correct.%0A%20%20%20%20assert_eq!(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20log.files%5B0%5D.as_any().downcast_ref%3A%3A%3CVec%3Cu8%3E%3E().unwrap()%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20b%22%5BInfo%5D%3A%20Info%20message%22%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%20%2F%2F%20wrong%20types%0A%7D)

Comment: This works, but I think that for unit testing purpose method proposed by Field is much better. But yours solution will be better in every other case.